# javascript array length > 10 sort google chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting

When I sort my array of objects by any column, it's working fine... till my array.length > 10... on google chrome (still working fine in firefox).

**EDIT : The problem when the length of the array exceeds 10 is that the sort simply sorts "randomly" my array.**

So I checked if my sort functions were returning something valid (0, negative or positive integer) and yes, they do.

I checked this by doing a simple console.log right before the return

```
console.log(a.wins - b.wins); // when comparing integers
console.log(a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'})); // when comparing strings
```

the outputs i had in my console were only numbers (-1, 0 or 1 for strings comparaisons & from -5 to 140 for integer comparaisons)

Any idea to solve my issue?

**EDIT2: well, let's try to put some code, here is the code when I compare usernames for example**

```
// So, when I click on Username column of my table, it calls this function
// The array I need to sort & display is: summoners
// You can see that I'm doing something weird in case my username is empty, 
// that's the way I found to put blank names after the 'z' letter so they
// appear at the end of the list when sorted ascending
if (jQuery(this).html() == 'Username'){
    var clonedSummoners = _.map(summoners, _.clone);
    summoners = summoners.sort(function(a, b){
        var first, second;
        if (a.Username == '') 
            first = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
        else
            first = a.Username;
        if (b.Username == '') 
            second = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
        else
            second = b.Username;
        console.log(first.localeCompare(second, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'}));
        return first.localeCompare(second, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'});
    });
    var testSort = true;
    for(var i=0; i<summoners.length; i++)
        if (summoners[i].id != clonedSummoners[i].id)
            testSort = false;
    if (testSort == true)
        summoners = summoners.reverse();
}

drawSummoners();
```

**EDIT 3: So, here is what I want & what I get:**

Let's say my array is:

```
summoners = [
    {'username' : 'calpton', 'age' : 19},
    {'username' : 'comics', 'age' : 12},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'newyork', 'age' : 47},
    {'username' : 'physics', 'age' : 14},
    {'username' : '', 'age' : 1},
    {'username' : 'azerty', 'age' : 2},
    {'username' : 'bob', 'age' : 5},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 37},
    {'username' : 'henry', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'therapy', 'age' : 27}
];
```

after calling my function above, I would like my summoners array to be sorted this way

```
summoners = [
    {'username' : 'azerty', 'age' : 2},
    {'username' : 'bob', 'age' : 5},
    {'username' : 'calpton', 'age' : 19},
    {'username' : 'comics', 'age' : 12},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 17}, // it doesn't matter
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 37}, // for these ones
    {'username' : 'henry', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'newyork', 'age' : 47},
    {'username' : 'physics', 'age' : 14},
    {'username' : 'therapy', 'age' : 27},
    {'username' : '', 'age' : 1},
];
```

but I will get instead :

```
summoners = [
    {'username' : 'calpton', 'age' : 19},
    {'username' : 'bob', 'age' : 5},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 37},
    {'username' : 'henry', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'comics', 'age' : 12},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'newyork', 'age' : 47},
    {'username' : 'physics', 'age' : 14},
    {'username' : '', 'age' : 1},
    {'username' : 'azerty', 'age' : 2},
    {'username' : 'therapy', 'age' : 27}
];
```

so, I guess it is not random because it will always sort it this way but the sort makes no sense.

**EDIT4: no, Username doesn't return undefined**

```
get Username(){
    if (typeof this.username == 'undefined')
        return '';
    else return this.username;
}
```

I'm in the context of a class

**FINAL EDIT:** OK, I found out what the problem is, the problem is that my array is a complex array of objects, I was trying to sort it by a property but sometimes, I had this property at the same value for like 7 out of 11 objects. The problem I had in chrome was that google chrome doesn't always sort the values that are equal in the same order whereas firefox always keep the same order. In my code (below Edit2), I check if the array is already sorted, and if yes, I reverse it, it worked well in firefox because it was always the same, in chrome it wasn't. I still don't get how it could mess up the initial sort tho but well, I simply added a second sort on a property I knew would be unique and it solved everything.

```
return first.localeCompare(second, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'}) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'});
```

the name is always there and unique there, so my array will always be sorted the same way.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code that directly demonstrates your issue?

Comment: So far you haven't described the problem. What's the problem? It returns undefined? It returns an empty array? It didn't sort? If it didn't sort are you SURE it didn't sort (did not change at all) or did it sort in an unexpected order?

Comment: sorry @slebetman, I've edited my post to answer your question

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Without sample data and context where code is used we have no way to reproduce

Comment: You still haven't described the problem. By randomly I assume it would sort `[3,2,1]` sometimes as `[1,3,2]` sometimes as `[3,1,2]` etc. We CANNOT answer this question because we don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: giving you sample data is pretty hard since i get everything by ajax and there are a lot of data, if it's still not clear, ill update the topic later in the day with all informations

Comment: `a.Username` and `b.Username` is undefined it should be `a.username` and `b.username`.

Comment: @Musa, well, you got the idea, obviously if I say it's working fine firefox & not in chrome, it can't be a syntax error problem...

Answer (score 0):

Well i did it in Chrome v51 as follows and the result is as expected.

```js
var summoners = [
    {'username' : 'calpton', 'age' : 19},
    {'username' : 'comics', 'age' : 12},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'newyork', 'age' : 47},
    {'username' : 'physics', 'age' : 14},
    {'username' : '', 'age' : 1},
    {'username' : 'azerty', 'age' : 2},
    {'username' : 'bob', 'age' : 5},
    {'username' : 'hello', 'age' : 37},
    {'username' : 'henry', 'age' : 17},
    {'username' : 'therapy', 'age' : 27}
],

   sorted = summoners.sort((a,b) => { var f = a.username || "zzz",
                                          s = b.username || "zzz";
                                      return f.localeCompare(s, void 0, {sensitivity: "base"});
                                    });
console.log(sorted);
```

P.S. You don't need to convert the undefined usernames to "" for the above snippet.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu. I upvote your answer but I can't validate it since it is not the solution to my problem, but you made me try and try and try again so I found out what was wrong, Gonna Edit my post to show it.

Comment: @PineApple34: cool.. I am curious about the solution. Let us know what was the problem.